# Função em Javascript não funciona

Tags: javascript

Criei uma função em Javascript para pegar a largura de uma `div` e depois adicionar essa largura em outras 4 divs, só que não está funcionando.

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var slidewidth = document.getElementById("slideshow").offsetWidth;
    var objs = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    for(var i in objs) {
        objs[i].style.width = slidewidth;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slideshow" id="slideshow">
    <div class="slideshowarea">
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por que "não está funcionando"? O que acontece?

Comment: Não está adicionando o width da div .slideshow na div com a classe .slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu `for` não está percorrendo os elementos recuperados. Você precisa alterá-lo para:

```
for(var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) ...
```

Depois, quando você vai inserir um valor em um `style` você precisa especificar a medida que você está usando. Isso significa que em css `100` não representa uma medida e sim `100px`. Quando você recupera o valor em `offsetWidth` o valor retornado é apenas `100`.

Você precisa setar `px` "manualmente" ao alterar o valor de width da sua classe `slide`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    
    var slidewidth = document.getElementById("slideshow").offsetWidth;
    var objs = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    
    for(var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
        objs[i].style.width = slidewidth + "px";
    }
    
}
```

```css
.slideshow {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.slide {
  width: 10px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow" id="slideshow">
    <div class="slideshowarea">
        <div class="slide">a</div>
        <div class="slide">b</div>
        <div class="slide">c</div>
        <div class="slide">d</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Caso o valor do width do `slideshow` esteja no css, você pode recuperar diretamente, sem necessitar incluir o `px` como medida do seu css, utilizando [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle):

```
var slidewidth = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("slideshow")).width;
```

Comment: Funcionou cara, muito obrigado

Comment: Que bom que te ajudei, Mateus! Ah, e não se esqueça de marcar uma das respostas como correta! :)

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente é porque você escreveu `for` errado.

Fazer `for (var i in objs)` irá iterar por todas as propriedades de `objs` (incluindo os indíces) e a cada laço a variávei `i` será um destes ites.

Você está tentando usar a variável `i` como índice da coleção `objs`. O certo seria fazer então a variável `i` receber **apenas** os índices possíveis para a coleção `objs`.

Ou então usar **`for of`** para atribuir à variável `i` cada elemento da coleção (modo 2 no exemplo).

Além disso tudo, você preicisa especificar a unidade de medida para o `width`, por exemplo `px`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var slidewidth = document.getElementById("slideshow").offsetWidth;
    var objs = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    for(var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
        objs[i].style.width = slidewidth + 'px';
    }
    
    // 2
    for(var i of objs) {      
      i.style.width = slidewidth + 'px';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow" id="slideshow">
    <div class="slideshowarea">
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Continua não funcionando :(